# typescript interface for object property [only refers to a type but is being used as a value here.]

Tags: typescript

```
state = {
    x: Array<any>(),
    y: number
}
```

`y` gives me the following error:

> only refers to a type but is being used as a value here.

which is understandable because it is object's property.

How can I use specify a type for this like the `x` one?

Comment: In your code you're defining a variable implicitly, but you aren't giving `y` any value (`x` is an array). You sure you want to do this? Or are you trying to define an interface/type?

Comment: so, aside from array, the only way to define a type in this context is by implicitly. 
Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are trying to assign to `state` a type with the given structure. If you want to declare a variable or a field you need to use `:`

```
let state : {
    x: Array<any>,
    y: number
}

//Or for a field:
class Foo {
    state: {
        x: Array<any>,
        y: number
    }
}
```

If you want to create such an object you need to assign values, not types:

```
let state = { x: [], y: 0}  // empty array for x
```